# How to make discord bot post in a specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord

So I am attempting to make a Discord bot post a message in a specific channel on a server, because it only posts to #everyone. I have looked at many other posts and can;t seem to get it. I am a complete moron at javascript and only know the very basic basics. The goal is when a user says "test" in a channel then the bot will output "Test" into a specific channel meant for logging certain responses. (This will become a offense log for when a user says something they aren't supposed to). This is what my code looks like so far:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'test') {
    client.channels.get("546117125702680596");
    channel.send('Test');
  }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
client.channels.get('546117125702680596').send('Test');
```

I'm not sure what `channel` is a reference to in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to the same channel as the origin message:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'test') {
    message.channel.send('Test');
  }
});
```

If you want to send into a specific channel:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'test') {
    const yourchannel = msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '546117125702680596')
    yourchannel.send('Test');
  }
});
```